# Good way to inject ConfigurationManager.AppSettings into class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to inject ConfigurationManager.AppSettings via Unity so that testing wise we can inject a specially formed collection of AppSettings.

For example, given a class `ClassName` with an interface `IClassName` and the ClassName implementation utilizes Configuration parameters, ie System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

```
public class ClassName : IClassName
{
  public ClassName(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection AppSettings)
  {
     this._AppSettings = AppSettings;
  }

  public void DoSomething() 
  {
    var urlToCall = _AppSettings["DoSomething.BaseUrl"] + "api/twitter/post";
    //...
  }
}
```

Since ConfigurationManager.AppSettings isn't a specific type, the actual return from the AppSettings is type `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` which could be too generic to just wire up to returning ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, what would be a good way, when registering the type, to constrain the Resolution to only when the parameter name is "AppSettings" and the type is `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`

In other words, can I use RegisterType with a constraint on the parameter name `AppSettings` and type `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` to return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings or maybe go down the configurable factory route but that leads me to the following implementation which is a lot of code to additionally write.  Ugh.  Factory would still needs to have a static variable to tweak it one way or the other, and using (web/app) configuration in tests can be hard to wire up.

I'd rather not do this: create an `IAppSettings` interface that can supply an instance that one implementation returns the values from ConfigurartionManager.AppSettings requested key and another implementation that just returns values from a NameValueCollection internally, that would be populated during testing.